# Adding text to document upon click event with Leaflet Marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm working with Leaflet and I would like to have it such that when the user clicks on a marker text will appear beside the map with a full description of what has been clicked on. A popup will already appear with a short description over the marker, but I'd also like a longer one. It should be pretty simple, except I cannot figure out how to properly reference the marker.

```
L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).bindPopup(function(layer) {
  return layer.feature.properties.popupContent
}).on('click', markerOnClick).addTo(map);

function markerOnClick(e) {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = (this.options.properties.description);
}
```

So I may have answered my own question by using this-

```
        function markerOnClick(e)
{        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=e.layer.feature.properties.description;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding your method to each marker by doing this. You need to do it with another way :

```
// It will add the method on click on each layer of your GeoJson
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
    document.getElementById("text").html(e.layer.feature.properties.description);
    });

}

geojson = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).bindPopup(function(layer) {
        return layer.feature.properties.popupContent
}).addTo(map);
```

Into the `function (e)` you should console log the variable e to see if you can access your data with `e.layer.feature.properties.description`